# Svn dont ignore files when add console

Tags: svn

I am working in a project with svn and have a file ".svnignore" with a list of folders to ignore.

When i run the command "svn add *", svn add all the files including the folders in the ".svnignore".

There is better way for add all the files in console except the folders inside the ".svnignore" list?

Answer (score 1):

Subversion do not use .svnignore file. It use svn:ignore properties: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html

Comment: In that link there is a section where explain that u can use a file for ignore patterns, like my example.

Comment: This file not specific for repository but for user/workstation. I never use it...